# Multiple view created with same name in document library CSOM (C#): 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library, csom, view

I am creating a custom view for a document library using following code:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    #region Create List

    ListCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new ListCreationInformation();
    listCreationInformation.Description = documentLibraryName;
    listCreationInformation.Title = documentLibraryName;
    listCreationInformation.TemplateType = 101;
    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.Add(listCreationInformation);
    clientContext.Load(list);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    #endregion

    #region Creating View

    string[] viewFields = new string[5];
    viewFields[0] = "Type";
    viewFields[2] = "Title";

    List documentLibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);

    ViewCreationInformation view = new ViewCreationInformation();
    view.Title = "DocumentsView";
    view.ViewFields = viewFields;
    view.SetAsDefaultView = false;

    documentLibrary.Views.Add(view);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    #endregion
}
```

Here view is successfully created and associated with document library.

**Question:** Is this view should available in all new document library I create later?

Because when I am creating new document library and create custom view again the same method then the document library shows 2 views with the same name.

First Library:

[image]

Second Library:

[image]

Not able to figure it out.

**Update:**

---

When I am trying to run the same code again for the new library name then in new library name there are two views with the same name.

I know there is a solution that get all views and if my view already exists then don't add the view to library. But I want to know what's the problem in this approach.

Comment: how are you creating second library?using template(.stp) of first library?

Comment: No, custom code CSOM C#.

Comment: Which code is used to create the new library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before adding the view, check if it exists first.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace COM
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // siteURL is the string that contains the site URL 
      string siteUrl = "http://serverName:50000/sites/Testing";
      // ClientContext object is used to get the context for the SharePoint objects
      ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
      Web web = clientContext.Web;
      List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");
      ViewCollection viewColl = list.Views;
      clientContext.Load(viewColl,
         views => views.Include(
            view => view.Title,
            view => view.Id));            
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
      foreach (View view in viewColl)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(view.Title + "--------" + view.Id);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```